# How to include static file folder in Electron Forge when build the application?

Tags: webpack, electron, electron-forge

I'm trying to use `Electron Forge` to build an app using the `TypeScript + Webpack` template. Since I need to change the app icon, I've created an `asset/icon` folder in the root directory to store my icons. This works perfectly while developing. But after I run the `make` command and try to run the app, it's saying can't find the icon and I see the `asset` was not included in the output. So my question is how can I include my static folder into the webpack during build process?

Comment: what's console.log(path) say?